# Access Union Sum Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to search for problem codes from 5 different field within a definable date range, then get a sum of each problem code that is returned. My Query below sums each problem code returned by each query but does not add totals from one query to another.

```
SELECT CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO, Count(CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO) AS CountOfPROBLEM_CO1
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE (((CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP) Between [Begin Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO, ([custrac].[problem_co])
HAVING (((CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO)<>""));

Union SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_2, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_2) AS CountOfPROB_2
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE (((CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP) Between [Begin Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_2, ([custrac].[prob_2])
HAVING (((CUSTRAC.PROB_2)<>""));

Union SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_3, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_3) AS CountofPROB_3
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE (((CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP) Between [Begin Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_3, ([custrac].[prob_3])
HAVING (((CUSTRAC.PROB_3)<>""));

Union SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_4, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_4) AS CountofPROB_4
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE (((CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP) Between [Begin Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_4, ([custrac].[prob_4])
HAVING (((CUSTRAC.PROB_4)<>""));

UNION SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_5, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_5) AS CountofPROB_5
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE (((CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP) Between [Begin Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_5, ([custrac].[prob_5])
HAVING (((CUSTRAC.PROB_5)<>""));
```

Comment: That's not even valid SQL. The UNION keyword can't be the first token after a semi-colon. Why are you using UNION anyway? That removes duplicates. Do you want to remove duplicates? I'm guessing not.

Comment: I don't think the way you are using `HAVING` is valid either.  `HAVING` is supposed to be used in conjunction with aggregate functions.

Comment: Let's also throw in the fact that the group by statement has the same column mentioned twice in all five queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, this should get you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ProbCode, SUM(A.ProbCount) AS ProbSum FROM
(
SELECT CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO AS ProbCode, Count(CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO) AS ProbCount
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP Between [Begin Date] AND [End Date] AND CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO <> ''
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROBLEM_CO 

UNION ALL

SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_2 AS ProbCode, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_2) AS ProbCount
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP Between [Begin Date] AND [End Date] AND CUSTRAC.PROB_2 <> ''
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_2

UNION ALL 

SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_3 AS ProbCode, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_3) AS ProbCount
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP Between [Begin Date] AND [End Date] AND CUSTRAC.PROB_3 <> ''
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_3

UNION ALL 

SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_4 AS ProbCode, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_4) AS ProbCount
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP Between [Begin Date] AND [End Date] AND CUSTRAC.PROB_4 <> ''
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_4 

UNION ALL 

SELECT CUSTRAC.PROB_5 AS ProbCode, Count(CUSTRAC.PROB_5) AS ProbCount
FROM CUSTRAC
WHERE CUSTRAC.DATE_SHIPP Between [Begin Date] AND [End Date] AND CUSTRAC.PROB_5 <> ''
GROUP BY CUSTRAC.PROB_5

) AS A

GROUP BY ProbCode
```